# How to solve pdf header signature not found error?

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I'm using iText in my java program for editing an existing pdf.The generated pdf could not open and it shows pdf header signature not found error.I'm using both my input and output file in a same name.

```
private static String INPUTFILE = "/sample.pdf";
private static String OUTPUTFILE = "/sample.pdf";       
public static void main(String[] args) 
        throws DocumentException,
        IOException 
{
    Document doc = new Document();
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(doc,new FileOutputStream(OUTPUTFILE));
    doc.open();
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(INPUTFILE);
    int n;
    n = reader.getNumberOfPages();
    System.out.println("No. of Pages :" +n);
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) 
    {
            if (i == 1)                 
            {            
                   Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(85,650,800,833);
                   PdfFormField pushbutton = PdfFormField.createPushButton(writer);
                   pushbutton.setWidget(rect, PdfAnnotation.HIGHLIGHT_PUSH);
                   PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent();
                   PdfAppearance app = cb.createAppearance(380,201);
                   app.rectangle(62,100,50,-1);
                   app.fill();
                   pushbutton.setAppearance(PdfAnnotation.APPEARANCE_NORMAL,app);
                   writer.addAnnotation(pushbutton);
                   PdfImportedPage page = writer.getImportedPage(reader, i);
                   Image instance = Image.getInstance(page);
                   doc.add(instance);
                }
```

Comment: It will be better if you show us your code

Comment: @ Francisco Puga....Above is my code

Comment: I think you should update your code with the suggestions given in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/8655157/930271

Answer (score 9):

Then try at first renaming the input file to **.bak**, and reading the **.bak**, and writing the **.pdf**. That could give a clue whether the error is with reading or writing.

**Itext** is not a single API, but several ones, mixed together. Quite hard sometimes. I did:

Close both the `PdfReader` and `FileInputStream`.

Close both `Document` and `PdfWriter`.

Comment: Closing the streams help me! Thank you.

Comment: exactly closing streams are important  .. thank you so much

Answer (score 4):

You may be importing from an empty source, or a invalid pdf file, in my case pdfCopy dont work, so here is the code I used.

```
Document document = new Document();
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, OutputStream );
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(dato.getBinaryStream());

PdfImportedPage page1 = writer.getImportedPage(reader, 1);
PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent();
cb.addTemplate(page1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);

 document.setPageSize(new Rectangle(page1.getWidth(),page1.getHeight()) );
```

...

This should work.

Comment: can you define 'dato' in dato.getBinaryStream() Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You should use `PdfCopy` instead of `PdfWriter.getInstance`, since it fails to update the PDF object references otherwise.

Furthermore instead of adding an `Image` to the document, you can utilize the `PdfCopy.addPage` method, which accepts a `PdfImportedPage` as parameter.

```
Document doc = new Document();
PdfCopy writer = new PdfCopy(doc,new FileOutputStream(OUTPUTFILE));
doc.open();
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(INPUTFILE);
int n = reader.getNumberOfPages();
System.out.println("No. of Pages :" +n);
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        if (i == 1) {            
               // removed code for clarity
               PdfImportedPage page = writer.getImportedPage(reader, i);

               writer.addPage(page);
            }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In My case PDF sample file was corrupted. upload new file it will works.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error and I just changed my PdfReader from reading InputStreams to read Strings. So, it works perfectly with:

```
public static void doMerge(List<String> list, OutputStream outputStream)
    throws DocumentException, IOException {
Document document = new Document();
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, outputStream);
document.open();
PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent();

for (String in : list) {
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(in);
    for (int i = 1; i <= reader.getNumberOfPages(); i++) {
        document.newPage();
        // import the page from source pdf
        PdfImportedPage page = writer.getImportedPage(reader, i);
        // add the page to the destination pdf
        cb.addTemplate(page, 0, 0);
    }
}

outputStream.flush();
document.close();
outputStream.close();
```

}

*Originally I took this code from http://www.mindfiresolutions.com/Java-Merging-multiple-PDFs-into-a-single-PDF-using-iText-671.php

Answer (score 0):

Your pdf should start with **%PDF**.You can check it.My file was corrupted.

Answer (score -1):

Your pdf bytes should start with "**%PDF-**" @Melahat Mindivanli answer is not 100% correct.

This is the validation code:

```
 public char checkPdfHeader() throws IOException {
    file.setStartOffset(0);
    String str = readString(1024);
    int idx = str.indexOf("%PDF-");
    if (idx < 0)
        throw new IOException("PDF header signature not found.");
    file.setStartOffset(idx);
    return str.charAt(idx + 7);
}
```